# How can I add month's name to a set of files

Tags: javascript, perl, batch-file

I'm a newbie to bat files and would like to know if there is a way for me to add the month's name to a set of pdf files I have without having to rename each and every one by using F2 or tab.

Basically, I have a set of billing reports for one of my clients, who has multiple sites which are in both pdf and excel format. I would like to include the month on the file name itself so that it would be easy for me to segregate them. For example, I have reports like:

- Audi Tetbury call information
- Volkswagen Tetbury call information
- BMW london call information

I would like to rename them to:

- Audi Tetbury call information February
- Volkswagen Tetbury call information February
- BMW London Call Information February.

Can someone please help me with this? Also I would request you to help me with some resources so that I can learn to create such things on my own in the future.

Comment: And, how do you detemine the name of the month to place in pdf file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way you can do it in windows batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set m=100
for %%a in (January February March April May June ^
    July August September October November December) do (
   set /A m+=1
   set month[!m:~-2!]=%%a
)

:: Do the rename. Remove echo after you verify output. 
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
    set "file=%%~dpnxa" & set "file=!file:\=\\!"
    echo file=!file!
    Call :GetFileMonthNum "!file!" C mnum     
    Call set fmonth=%%month[!mnum!]%%
    echo ren "%%a" "%%~na !fmonth!%%~xa"
    echo ren "%%~na.xls" "%%~na !fmonth!.xls"
)

goto :eof

:GetFileMonthNum <file> <created/accessed/modified> <outVar>
setlocal
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in (
  'wmic datafile where "name='%~1'" get creationdate^,lastaccessed ^
  ^,lastmodified^|findstr /r "\.*-.*"'
) do (
    set opts=%2
    if "!opts:~0,1!" EQU "C" set "dt=%%a"
    if "!opts:~0,1!" EQU "A" set "dt=%%b"
    if "!opts:~0,1!" EQU "M" set "dt=%%c"
    set "mm=!dt:~4,2!"
)
endlocal & set %~3=%mm%
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get stats about each file using "stat" command. Then you grep the line with the date you want; stat offers "Access", "Modify", and "Change" dates. Then you just read the month from that string and rename your file.
You can do something like this, assuming you want to label each file with the month it was modified in (you can also try Access, or Change, in addition to Modify):

```
foreach my $file ($pathToYourFolder/*.txt) # or pdf or anything
{
    my $date = `stat $file | grep Modify`;
    $date =~ /(\d+)-(\d+)-/;
    my ($year,$month) = ($1,$2);
    `mv $file $month-$file`; 
}
```

You can also add the month to the end of each file's name (you can leverage File::Basename or something to make sure you add the month before file's extension).

Comment: Don't use backticks to invoke an external command that may or may not be available on the OP's OS when Perl provides a [built-in equivalent](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html). There are still [portability issues](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#stat) with Perl's stat but at least it will run on Windows.